# Is there a way to define custom tasks in a VSCode extension?

Tags: c, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

i am trying to create an extension for **C** language right now which will provide the user a set of tasks for compiling the code with different flags and different compilers(like **afl-gc**c which is used for fuzzing) or will run the program with a specific input file. Whats is the best way to register those tasks? I've used a Task Provider specified in the API but the results are not very good and was wondering if there is another way to do it?

Comment: "I've used a Task Provider specified in the API but the results are not very good" - task providers are the way to do it. Hard to help if you don't specify what issues you had with them.

Comment: basically what I want to do is define the task as a json like
`
command:[tag:... ,
                 label:....,
] 

plus I want the task to depend on another task also and the new Task() constructor doesn't have the option to create a dependency.